# Differentiate this function

Tags: calculus

Differentiate this function

$$f(x)=\frac{3x-1}{2x+7}+x^{-15}+ \cos( \ln(x))$$

I got the answer $\displaystyle -\frac{15}{x^{16}}+\frac{2-6x}{(2x+7)^2}+ \frac{3}{2x+7}$ but its wrong

Comment: You just missed $\dfrac{d}{dx} \cos(\ln(x))$.

Comment: fyi, it's differentiate, not derivate :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x)=\frac{3x-1}{2x+7}+x^{-15}+ \cos( \ln(x))$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{3(2x+7)-2(3x-1)}{(2x+7)2}-15x^{-16}-\sin( \ln(x))\frac{1}{x}=$$
$$=\frac{23}{(2x+7)2}-\frac{15}{x^{16}}-\frac{\sin( \ln(x))}{x}$$